# Accessing LDAP through Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ldap

I'm new to LDAP and was wondering if I could access my LDAP entries using JNDI library in netbeans?
I tried using the code snippets given on the internet but I'm receiving this error:
javax.naming.CommunicationException: mydomain.com :389 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: You can access LDAP *without* JNDI in NetBeans, via the LDAP explorer built into the Services tab, but I suspect what you're really asking is how to access LDAP from *Java*, via JNDI, which is already very extensively documented and too broad to answer here.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the suggestion. I tried via netbeans explorer, but got the same error. Does netbeans access the host through the internet, because my LDAP server is not on localhost.

Comment: Thats a DNS problem, or more probably a wrong hostname. `mydomain.com' is unknown. Nothing to do with LDAP whatsoever. Use the correct hostname.